# python string comparison failed

Tags: python, string, compare, match

In python, I wrote a program to compare two strings.
The coedes are below

```
d = data.iloc[0]

cmpdate = d['quant_date']

print(cmpdate)

if (cmpdate=='2010-03-18'):

    print("=================", dt)

else:

    print("xxxxxxxxxxxxx", cmpdate)
```

the results are

```
2010-03-18

xxxxxxxxxxxxx 2010-03-18
```

tow strings are exactly same.
what is the problem?
TIA

Comment: `print(type(cmpdate), repr(cmpdate))`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you convert both of the dates to datetime format
and check the result
use `to_datetime()` function
This works fine